# Rust-Analyzer failed to load workspace, failing because of dependencies

Tags: linux, rust

```
[ERROR rust_analyzer::reload] failed to switch workspaces: 
rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: 
Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file 
/home/supreetsingh/Documents/SavedPrograms/Rust/remind-me/Cargo.toml,
cargo 1.57.0-nightly (7fbbf4e8f 2021-10-19): Failed to run `cargo metadata --manifest-path
/home/supreetsingh/Documents/SavedPrograms/Rust/remind-me/Cargo.toml`: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: Updating crates.io index error: failed to select a version for the requirement `phf = "^0.11"` 
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.0, ... location searched: crates.io index required by package `tokio-postgres v0.7.7` ... which satisfies dependency `tokio-postgres = "^0.7.7"` (locked to 0.7.7) of package `postgres v0.19.4` ... which satisfies dependency `postgres = "^0.19.4"` (locked to 0.19.4) of package `remind-me v0.1.0 (/home/supreetsingh/Documents/SavedPrograms/Rust/remind-me)
```

So this problem is just arising in one rust project of mine. Cargo is in the path and this problem arose when I added one new dependency to my project and now I am stuck with this.
I have tried looking for the answer on the internet and did not find success yet, I do not know what else to try next.

`cargo metadata --manifest-path <path to the file>`
Works in the console I do not know why is this not working right now.

I am running this on Manjaro and my text editor is Vim with YouCompleteMe being used for AutoComplete.

If someone can point out what is wrong with the dependencies, I would be very thankful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

phf 0.11 requires Rust 1.60. You need to either update your Rust compiler to at least that version, or follow the chain of dependencies and downgrade the `postgres` crate so that you don't require `phf` 0.11.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, turns out this is the problem. I am running rust 1.63 which is the latest version, I downgrade the postgres crate and use it. Thanks for the answer.